# What Does the SQL dash character do?

Tags: sql, syntax

In a SQL statement I am debugging, I found a `-` used in a way I don't recognize:

it appears in this SELECT statement between "Book_Balance" and "Participation_Lookups"

```
SELECT "LNIMPR"."Book_Balance" - "Participation_Lookups"."Participation Principal Assets" AS "C7" 
FROM ...
```

What does the `-` do in the above context?

Comment: Yeah I defenitely overthought it

Comment: actually the dots create confusion otherwise it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

It is subtracting the two columns.

They must both be numeric values and in SQL to [subtract](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqloperators.php) you use the minus sign `-`.

If `Book_balance` is 100 and `Participation Principal Assets` is 25, then is it basically saying:

```
select 100 -25 as C7
from ...
```

This calculation is occurring for each row that is returned.

Comment: @John Don't feel dumb! It is just one of those moments that happens to all of us! :)

Answer (score 2):

Numeric subtraction, as in 10 - 4 = 6

Comment: Can you do a proof for this?